# Code changes are not visible in local after using Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am new with Docker, I just finished the installation and the syncro with my app and database.

I succeed to access to my app and navigate in http://localhost:3000/

Unfortunately, if I edit the code in the IDE (Visual Studio Code), the changes don't appeared on http://localhost:3000/

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.4.5'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  redis:
    image: 'redis:5.0.8'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'
    ports:
        - '6379:6379'

  [MY_APP_NAME]:
    build: '.'
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'redis'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  sidekiq:
    build: '.'
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'redis'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
volumes:
  postgres: {}
  redis: {}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6-slim

ARG SECRET_KEY_BASE

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential nodejs libpq-dev git --fix-missing --no-install-recommends && gem install bundler -v 2.3.22

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install -j4

ADD . $APP_HOME

RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY_BASE}.to_s AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}, RAILS_ENV=production

VOLUME ["/app/public"]

CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

I already tried without success to add in my config/environments/development.rb

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
config.cache_classes = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your volumes problem

In `Dockerfile` you have `/myapp` but in `docker-compose.yml` -- `/app`

Use some uniform name in both files